# stuck with angular and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

using mvc 4 web api project.

in index. cshtml page i have loaded all required. js files....

order is
in index.cshtml,

jquery latest version

jquery-ui latest version

jquery-sortable

angularjs latest vesrsion

lets say in dashboard.html

```
    <div>
     <table id="sortTable“>
       <tr>
           <td>first
           </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>second
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

i want to make movable TR. so i have added jquery-sortable.

in angular controller dashboard. js

```
 dashboardCtrl{
 // controller is working..... dont wry abt it
$("#sortTable"). sortable ()..........    
}
```

this line gives error in angularjs that sortable is unknown object or something....

i have changed order to

jquery

jquery-ui

angularjs

jquery-sortable.....

still not working...

i have tried other orders too....

but nothing is working...  have already asked question but no reply...

help me..  i want to drag row and make it movable in table.  in short, want to reorder table rows...

applied ul...  li....  concept tooo.......

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not really meant to be doing UI interactions like sortable.  But the great thing about angular is that you can write directives that allow you to do that in the DOM. And usually someone has already written a directive that does what you are looking for.

In your case, I would look into these two directives.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

Both are well documented and easy to use.  Just do the install, inject the dependency in your app, and you're all set!